# get a value from an element and add to the end of each href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a table that consist of many table rows with columns.

and I'd take a value from each td with classname: *routecode* and I have to add that value to the end of closest href of each tr. I would add this to the value of routecode link.

I wrote the below code but it does not work and the value is not added to the end of link.

Here is my code:

```js
$(".list").each(function(index, element) {
  var routecode = $(this).closest("tr").find(".routecode").text()
  var linkk = $(this).attr("href")
  $(this).attr("href", linkk + routecode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr class=" odd">
      <td class="routecode">TK26</td>
      <td>
        <a class="list" href="/reservation/route/info.bc?dmnid=2893&routecode=">Edit </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class=" odd">
      <td class="routecode">tkeee</td>
      <td>
        <a class="list" href="/reservation/route/info.bc?dmnid=2893&routecode=">Edit </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Route code is added to the end of the link. What's the issue?

Comment: Its added. Just inspect the element

Comment: Yess they are , please check your code again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

You are missing semicolon `;` end of line..

Demo here: https://output.jsbin.com/nolomec

https://jsbin.com/nolomec/2/edit?html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".list").each(function(index, element) {
    var routecode = $(this).closest("tr").find(".routecode").text();
    var linkk = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", linkk + routecode);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr class="odd">
<td class="routecode">TK26</td>
<td>                                       
<a class="list" href="/reservation/route/info.bc?dmnid=2893&routecode=">Edit </a>
</td>                                   
</tr>

<tr class=" odd">
<td class="routecode">tkeee</td>
 <td>                                       
<a  class="list" href="/reservation/route/info.bc?dmnid=2893&routecode=">Edit </a>
</td>                                   
</tr>                             
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the `routecode` not getting appended in the question?